# How to use Selenium in Python to capture a dynamic element on Google Calendar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, bots

I'm creating an auto-login Google Calendar bot and I've run into an issue where the xpath for a certain element keeps changing every time I login(but it has a similar form). Here are some examples:

//*[@id="c307"]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/label/div[1]/div/input
//*[@id="c236"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/span/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input'
//*[@id="c27"]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/label/div[1]/div/input

and etc.
How can I use Selenium to click on this dynamic element given that it always changes? Help will be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What does the html of the element look like?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a querySelector over an xpath

[MDN web docs document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

An implementation of this would look like:

```
driver.execute_script('document.querySelector("#specific_element_id").click()')
```

This code finds an element that looks something like `<input type="button" id="specific_element_id">` and will click it.